# Magento 2.2.4 Backend menu issue not working except catalog>Category page and shows 2 errors

Tags: magento2, layout, backend, magento2.2.4, adminmenu

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setActive() on boolean in vendor\magento\module-backend\Model\View\Result\Page.php on line 27
Error: Call to a member function setActive() on boolean in vendor\magento\module-backend\Model\View\Result\Page.php on line 27
```

Here is what I tested

1) When I disable all the modules It works fine and If I enable any single custom module It throws an error as above mentioned.

2) I tried all the commands for setup upgrade, compilation, cache flush, cache clean, static content deploy and developer mode and production mode as well.

2) Some solution suggested that to remove generation/metadata/global.php, I tried but no luck.

I'm using wamp+win10, PHP 7.1.16, Apache 2.4.~ and mysql5.7.21

Comment: please share any module menu.xml file

Comment: I resolved this issue. I will post the steps soon. Thanks Kunj! for taking the time to review my question.

Comment: Could you share how yopu resolve this issue..I am facing such issue..

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setActive() on boolean in magento\module-backend\Model\View\Result\Page.php:27

Comment: Put setActive() method and return true in controller file. This is for ACL